# iPhone Close Keyboard When After Hitting Home Button

Tags: iphone, keyboard

How to I close the iPhone keyboard when a user has hit the Home button while the keyboard was up?

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    [yourtextfield resignFirstResponder];
}
```